# Travelling in Schengen with UK passport

Tags: uk, schengen, uk-citizens, eu-citizens

I’m a dual Irish and British passport holder, and due to travel from Amsterdam to Slovenia - usually I would travel with my Irish passport but due to circumstances I only have my UK passport available right now. Would there be issues travelling with my UK passport without any entry stamps of me entering the EU/Schengen region? I have a copy of my Irish passport on my phone and so could explain lack of stamps.

For clarity, I live in the Netherlands and am a resident there. When entering/exiting, I always use my Irish passport.

Comment: Why would a lack of stamps be an issue? You'd just be a normal tourist in the eyes of immigration officials....

Comment: I'm not sure if it's legal for EU citizens to enter EU with non-EU passport

Comment: @Ozzy *Article 12 (Presumption as regards fulfilment of conditions of duration of stay) 1. If the travel document of a third-country national does not bear an entry stamp, **the competent national authorities may presume that the holder does not fulfil**, or no longer fulfils, the conditions of duration of stay applicable within the Member State concerned.*

Comment: It would be up to the authority to deside if a copy of your Irish passport on your phone is acceptible. An Airline may have problems with this. *Article 12 2. The presumption referred to in paragraph 1 **may be rebutted** where the third-country national provides, **by any means, credible evidence**, such as...*

Comment: @MarkJohnson I still don't see the issue Mark. If this person is in Ireland, then travels to Amsterdam on their UK passport they would just enter normally as a tourist and get stamped in.

Comment: @Ozzy The OP states that they are travelling from 'Amsterdam to Slovenia' and later 'lack of stamps'.  Therefore the OP is **not** entering the Schengen Area with their UK passport.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I see that now... I was assuming entering Schengen at AMS and then traveling on. Not starting from Amsterdam. Whoops!

Comment: If you have an Irish passport then you may apply for an Irish passport card.  This is quick and easy.  It is the size of a credit card and hence very easy to carry.  You may use it to travel in the EU, EEA, and Switzerland.  You can even use it to enter the UK but I have notvtried that.  The UK no longer accepts EU ID cards in general but it does still accept Irish ones.

Comment: More about the Irish passport card here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100201/where-can-i-use-an-irish-passport-card.  One thing to watch is that the card is valid for a maximum if 5 years not 10 as for the book.  It won't last beyond the book.  So, if you get one while there less than 5 years left in your book then it will expire at the same time.

Comment: More about using an Irish passport card to enter the UK here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174935/can-i-use-an-irish-passport-card-to-enter-the-uk/174937#174937

Comment: How do you plan to travel?  If you're flying, with which airline?

Answer (score 2):

> Would there be issues travelling with my UK passport without any entry stamps of me entering the EU/Schengen region?

Possibly, but not likely.  You could encounter some officers checking travelers' documents, but as you know such checks aren't systematic in the way that they are when you enter or leave the Schengen area.

If you *do* encounter such checks and they ask why you don't have any stamps in your passport, you'll probably be fine by explaining that you are an Irish citizen and telling them why you don't have your Irish passport.  They could probably detain you to check out your story, but they will probably decide that it's not worth their time.

If you're flying, however, the airline might -- or might not -- require you to show that you're in the Schengen area legally (low-cost carriers are notorious for this).  If they do, you might have a more difficult time of it without an Irish passport.

Answer (score 2):

No, in my experience you shouldn't have any issues.

I am a UK (only) citizen, resident in the Netherlands. I have no stamps in my passport, as the Dutch border control don't stamp residents' passports. When I fly within the Schengen region I always use my UK passport as ID (e.g. at check in or at the gate - I've never encountered any other checks) and nobody has ever even looked for a stamp, let alone ask to see my resident's permit.

Comment: In a serious check, you can show proof of your residence status, the OP cannot.

Comment: @MarkJohnson That's true, but it also applies in day-to-day life in the Netherlands (where all adults are supposed to carry ID, but I've never been asked for mine). Is there anything about travelling to Slovenia that changes things?

Comment: The Freedon of movement Article 5 Right of entry (*(1) Without prejudice to the provisions on travel documents applicable to national border controls, Member States shall grant Union citizens leave to enter their territory with a valid identity card or passport and ...*), still requires a valid ID or passport to cross national borders. Thus travelling with a 3rd country passport without an authentication to be in the Schengen Area (entry stamp at present) is only asking for trouble by any random checks. Once their EU citizenship, later, has been determined any charges will be dropped.

Comment: Is is it worth the bother? (to long to be included in the previous comment)